# ESP 12E Module ESP8266 | Unable to call Https Api. Connection Failed

Tags: arduino-esp8266, esp8266wifi

I tried everything but every time I am getting "Connection Failed" for `client.connect`.
I have used https://gorest.co.in/public-api/user/123
Used the fingerprints well. Using ESP-12E Module
Any pointer will be of great help

Fingerprint I have copied from broswer

```
#define TEST_HOST "gorest.co.in"
#define TEST_HOST_FINGERPRINT "‎‎f1 5f 90 b4 73 c5 98 1e ec 08 92 69 8c e5 28 f8 7f b3 a8 e8"

// Use WiFiClientSecure class to create TLS connection
  WiFiClientSecure client;
  Serial.print("connecting to ");
  Serial.println(TEST_HOST);

  Serial.printf("Using fingerprint '%s'\n", TEST_HOST_FINGERPRINT);
  //client.setInsecure();
  client.setFingerprint(TEST_HOST_FINGERPRINT);
  
  client.setTimeout(10000);
  if (!client.connect(TEST_HOST, 443)) {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    return;
  }
```

Comment: go.in or co.in?

Comment: You'd be more likely to get help if you considered https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Url is https://gorest.co.in/public-api/users/123.

Comment: you had `go.in` in the code snippet until Marcel edited it. is it working if you fix it to `co.in`?

Comment: Code is not working even after fixing it. I put a hack and disabled the secure call by mentioning below so at least I can move ahead further to call my AWS apigateway exposed on https.   -> client.setInsecure(true)

Comment: But I am still looking for the solution or pointer.